# Displaying stateful session bean values on JSP

Tags: jsp, ejb-3.0, stateful-session-bean

I have used DI to inject a **Stateful** Session Bean across 3 servlets (which take data from forms across 3 JSP pages), so that data received by all 3 servlets can be stored in it. When I print all the data of the Bean in the last servlet, it gets printed successfully.

However when I try to print the same data of the bean on a JSP using `<jsp:useBean>` tag, and `scope=session` all data shows null. I tried using InitialContext to get the bean using JNDI but it could not find the required bean (probably because I injected the bean using DI!). I even tried putting the EJB bean in an `HttpSession` but it threw a `ClassCastException`.

How do I print the values of my Stateful Session Bean on a JSP?

Comment: When the same DI used in servlets, is tried in `<% %>` JSP scriptlet tag, an error is generated which says 'annotation type not applicable to this kind of a declaration'. Tried using both `@EJB` and `@Inject`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Marked the session bean with `@SessionScoped` annotation